# How to reload block in Magento?

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I'm working on a module for Christmas on Magento. 
Each day a pop-up appears on the index page of the website.
This pop-up will contain an image and a link.

To load the pop-up, I define what css to use (module.phtml):

```
<?php
    $today = explode(".",date("d.m.y")); 
    $month = $today[1];
    $day = $today[0];
    $file = 'POP UP '.$day.'.jpg';      
    $class = 'block block-AdventCalendar'.$day; 
?>

<div class="<?php echo $class ?>">
</div>
```

Example in the CSS file (app-base.css):

```
.block-AdventCalendar1 {
 background-image: url('../images/popupAdvent/POP UP 1.jpg');
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 height:350px;
 width :700px;
}
```

This code works fine, but when the day changes Magento loads the wrong CSS class.
To display the correct image I must clear the Magento cache each day.

However, when I modify something in the phtml file, the changes are displayed immediately, only the inline CSS is not reloaded.

Does anybody have an idea to force the phtml to load the right css?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
```

To clear the Magento cache after your code loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a JavaScript alternative:

```
<script>
  var dateObj = new Date();
  var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
  var element = document.getElementById('your_div_id');

  if (element) {
    element.className += element.className ? ' block-AdventCalendar'+day : 'block-AdventCalendar'+day;
  }
</script>
```

Add this after the div you want to add the class to. Also, give your div a unique ID ( `<div id="your_div_id">...</div>` )

Comment: Thanks Alex for answer. I've try with JS, the probème is the same. All the phtml file is reload except this line while cache isn't empty.

Comment: Well that's strange. Javascript is executed in the browser, caching should have virtually no effect on it :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not due to the CSS.
If I alter it or the phtml, all change are immediate.

Only the div class stay unchanged

```
<div class="<?php echo $class ?>">
```